Which accelerates more? A pulley of constant diameter or a pulley of decreasing diameter?
Given two pulleys. One is a straight drum for the rope to wrap itself around while maintaining a constant diameter as the rope unwinds. The other is a a drum with a spiral that the rope winds itself around so the diameter decreases as the rope unwinds. Say a weight is attached to said pulleys to power a vehicle in a frictionless environment, which of the two will have the highest acceleration?
The pulleys would have the same external diameter of 39mm and would both weight less than 0.1kg.


Need a little more info. Do they both have the same mass or the  same moment of inertia? Do they have the same external radius?

They would have the same external radius of 39 mm but would not have the same moment of inertia since their mass would be different. We're talking about plastic pulleys that would weigh below 0.1kg.

Can you sketch how you power your vehicle with theses two pulleys?

I added a sketch

BTW the way it is wound the spiral pulley is going to be in back of the vehicle. I hope this was the intent.

Interesting problem.
Each rotating part has an $R$ value for the radius, an $m$ value for the mass, and an $I$ value for the mass moment of inertia.
In addition, the dropped weight and the frame of the car have mass that need to be accounted for.

This set up the kinematics where the speed of the car is related to the speed of the weight being dropped.
I think the first question that needs to be answered afterward is what is the mathematical model of the acceleration and how is the radius of the lower pulley affect it?
The second question is if the lower puller radius varied by the amount the weight is dropped (and hence distance traveled), how would that affect the acceleration?
Overall you can say that there is a fixed amount of potential energy in the system which is covered to kinetic energy so the final velocity is always going to be the same. I think it is worth looking into the math of this to understand what gearing between the wheels and drop weight provides the optimal acceleration.
There is an additional detail to consider as bigger pulleys mean higher mass and higher mass moment of inertia which hinders performance, but on the other hand, small pulleys limit the speed at which the weight drops limiting the acceleration.
This means that there is a single optimal value for the radius of the lower pulley and any variation from that value would result in sub-optimal acceleration.
You would only need the conical pulley if you wanted a specific acceleration profile as you where trying to achieve some specific speed at some specific distance. But none of those requirements are detailed in the question.

The kinematics in terms of velocities is
$$\begin{gathered}v_{{\rm car}}=\omega_{{\rm lower}}R_{{\rm wheel}}\\
v_{{\rm weight}}=\omega_{{\rm upper}}R_{{\rm upper}}=\omega_{{\rm lower}}R_{{\rm lower}}
\end{gathered}$$
which leads to the kinematics in terms of acceleration
$$\begin{gathered}a_{{\rm car}}=\alpha_{{\rm lower}}R_{{\rm wheel}}\\
a_{{\rm weight}}=\alpha_{{\rm upper}}R_{{\rm upper}}=\alpha_{{\rm lower}}R_{{\rm lower}}
\end{gathered}$$
with solution of
$$\begin{aligned}a_{{\rm car}} & =\frac{R_{{\rm wheel}}}{R_{{\rm lower}}}a_{{\rm weight}}\\
\alpha_{{\rm lower}} & =\tfrac{1}{R_{{\rm lower}}}a_{{\rm weight}}\\
\alpha_{{\rm upper}} & =\tfrac{1}{R_{{\rm upper}}}a_{{\rm weight}}
\end{aligned}$$
I took the sketch apart in order to understand the forces/torques between different components

and the equations that result
$$\begin{gathered}T_{{\rm weight}}=m_{{\rm weight}}\left(g-a_{{\rm weight}}\right)\\
R_{{\rm upper}}\left(T_{{\rm weight}}-T_{{\rm lower}}\right)=I_{{\rm upper}}\alpha_{{\rm upper}}\\
R_{{\rm lower}}T_{{\rm lower}}-\tau_{{\rm lower}}=I_{{\rm lower}}\alpha_{{\rm lower}}\\
\tau_{{\rm lower}}-R_{{\rm wheel}}F_{{\rm car}}=I_{{\rm wheel}}\alpha_{{\rm lower}}\\
F_{{\rm car}}=m_{{\rm total}}a_{{\rm car}}
\end{gathered}$$
which yields to the mathematical model for acceleration
$$\boxed{\frac{a_{{\rm car}}}{g}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{R_{{\rm wheel}}}+\frac{m_{{\rm lower}}+m_{{\rm upper}}}{2\,m_{{\rm weight}}\,R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)R_{{\rm lower}}+\left(\frac{I_{{\rm wheel}}+m_{{\rm total}}R_{{\rm wheel}}^{2}}{m_{{\rm weight}}R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)\frac{1}{R_{{\rm lower}}}}}$$
where $m_{\rm  total}$ is the total mass of the vehicle.
The above form of $f(x) \propto \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}$ has a maximum value for
$$ R_{{\rm lower}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{I_{{\rm wheel}}+m_{{\rm total}}R_{{\rm wheel}}^{2}}{m_{{\rm weight}}R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{R_{{\rm wheel}}}+\frac{m_{{\rm lower}}+m_{{\rm upper}}}{2\,m_{{\rm weight}}\,R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)}}$$
The shape of the acceleration curves looks kind of like this

with a peak acceleration of
$$\left(\frac{a_{{\rm car}}}{g}\right)_{{\rm max}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{R_{{\rm wheel}}}+\frac{m_{{\rm lower}}+m_{{\rm upper}}}{2\,m_{{\rm weight}}\,R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)\left(\frac{I_{{\rm wheel}}+m_{{\rm total}}R_{{\rm wheel}}^{2}}{m_{{\rm weight}}R_{{\rm wheel}}}\right)}}$$

See updated answer above.

with  these equations
for the pully
$$m\,a=-m\,g+T_1\\
 I_p\,\alpha_p=(T_2-T_1)\,r_p\\
a=r_p\,\alpha_p
$$
for the spiral
$$I_s\,\alpha_s=\tau-T_2\,r_s$$
and the constraint equation
$$ r_s\alpha_s=r_p\alpha_p$$
(where p for pully and s for spiral. $~\tau~$ is external spiral  torque . $~T_i~$ rope tension.)
you obtain 5 equations for the unknows $~ a~,\alpha_p~,\alpha_s~,T_1~,T_2 $
where the spiral radius $~r_s~$ is a function of the spiral rotation $~\phi_s(t)~$
the acceleration a of mass m is:
$$a=\ddot z=\frac {(\tau-r_s(\phi_s)\,m\,g)\,r_p^2\,r_s(\phi_s)}{\,[r_s(\phi_s)]^2(\,I_p+m\,r_p^2)+I_s\,r_p^2}\tag 1$$
the angular acceleration of the spiral is:
$$\alpha_s=\ddot\phi_s=\frac {(\tau-r_s(\phi_s)\,m\,g)\,r_p^2}{\,[r_s(\phi_s)]^2(\,I_p+m\,r_p^2)+I_s\,r_p^2}\tag 2$$
for a given function $~r_s=r_s(\phi_s)~$ you can solve Eq. (1) and (2) and obtain the acceleration $~a(t)~$
